# Error at "tns run android" of "extract:tns-android: verb lock using"

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I created an application using command

> tns create HelloWorld --template nativescript-template-tutorial

The next step suggested [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1) is to run the app using

> tns run android

When done, it continuously prints following in my console:

> Installing tns-android[       ...........] - extract:tns-android: verb lock using C:\Users\monu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_locks\staging-ec0e4e06dfdc2677.lock for C:\mayur\work\trails\Test1\node_modules.sta

What could be wrong?

Comment: Eh, looks like npm 5 is erroring out on you. Try `npm cache clean`, and if all else fails afterwards, consider downgrading to npm 3.10

Comment: I uninstalled nativeScript ..deleted all the references  of it from my computer.. and re-installed it..its working smooth now.

Comment: @Mayurb with npm 5?